# Laravel scheduler timezone

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, scheduler, laravel-scheduler

How do I set the Laravel scheduler to run a task at a specific time in a certain timezone? The server is set to UTC, but I want to run the task at 12 noon every Monday in the `Pacific/Auckland` timezone.

E.g. this will work, but the timezone is UTC:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->command('run-report')->weekly()->mondays()->at('12:00'));
}
```

Answer (score 19):

You can do it using **timezone()** method:

```
$schedule->command('run-report')->weekly()->mondays()->at('12:00')->timezone('Pacific/Auckland');
```

Comment: It would be hard to put all methods in the Laravel guide, but you can always check the API docs (e.g. https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Console/Scheduling/Event.html) or just browse the code

Comment: Hmm, so I tried this, left it for 2 weeks, but it never got triggered.

Comment: when you call timezone() it just sets the timezone that is later applied to a DateTime object being used to compare current time with what you set in the scheduler - it can only impact the time, but won't prevent the command from running. I can't really tell why your task was not executed - you need to do some debugging on your own. Make sure that schedule:run command was run, check if there are no errors in the log files, maybe add some logging on your own